# Product with special requirements on conjugation

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Being a non-specialist in algebra, I stumbled upon the following question:

For a real or complex associative algebra $A$, let $A^\times$ denote its group of units. Is there a natural semigroup structure on $A \times A$ such that for all $u \in A^\times$ and all $a \in A$, we have: $(a,u) \in (A \times A)^\times$, and for every $b,v \in A$, there is $z \in A$ with $(a,u) \cdot (b,v) \cdot (a,u)^{-1} = (u b u^{-1}, z) $?

(In particular, this means that the first component of the result of the conjugation above is independent of $a \in A$).